# Inno Setup - Deny ACL for registry keys

Tags: inno-setup, acl

I need my setup to create a registry key or value which has deny-type read policy.

I've tried that:

```
Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "Software\mySoftware\myKey"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "PASSWORD"; ValueData: "{code:GetUserEnteredPassword}"; Permissions: admins-full system-read;
```

Unfortunately, that way created value 'PASSWORD' is still readable for users.

Please let me know if there is any idea how to create deny permissions with Inno Setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with Inno Setup. It does not support anything like `users-deny`-style permissions.

What you can do, is to execute the `regini` command or PowerShell script from `[Run]` section or Pascal Script:

- [How to change registry values or permissions from a command line or a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/change-registry-values-permissions) (`regini`)
- [Change Permissions on Registry key via Command line](https://serverfault.com/q/331046/168875) (`regini` and PowerShell)

Comment: I implemented PowerShell script and put in [Run] section.